# Multiple subdomains on CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare

Is it possible to set up DNS records using CloudFlare that would allow me to have subdomains pointing to two different ports on my local machine?

For example, one application running on port 80, and another on port 8880? According to this link the ports should both be supported:
https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supporting-more-ports/

I'd like to have:
sub1.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4:80
sub2.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4:8880

I've looked at SRV records, but it doesn't seem to allow IP addresses as targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy like nginx and use it along with Cloudflare for the purpose.

Check this link to learn about installing and configuring nginx as reverse proxy.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

an example configuration looks like this

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://local_ip:8081;

    }
}


    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://local_ip:port;

    }
}
```